# memory Analyzer - MAT

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have recently started using memory Analyzer- Mat in eclipse. I checked my application It showed me following Leak suspects

```
suspect 1:
The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 1,361,880 (34.60%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.util.LongSparseArray[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
android.util.LongSparseArray[]
android.content.res.Resources

suspect 2:

8,204 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 545,400 (13.86%) bytes. 

Keywords
java.lang.String

suspuct 3:

11 instances of "android.graphics.Bitmap", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 531,496 (13.50%) bytes.

Biggest instances:

android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0xa4e70af0 - 281,944 (7.16%) bytes.
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0xa504d180 - 65,600 (1.67%) bytes.
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0xa505dae8 - 65,600 (1.67%) bytes.


Keywords
android.graphics.Bitmap
```

I tried to find out the memory leak in my programme but couldn't figure out what these suspect memory leak message are trying to say?

For experiment - I tried MAT with just a simple application hello world. When I checked the memory leak it was still showing me first two memory leaks. How can be a memory leak on just displaying a single hello world.

What I am doing wrong here or just ignore the memory leak suspect messages.

Comment: It is not a `leak`, you have to read! It is a `suspect`. MAT can only guess what could be a leak. The programmer have to decide if a given suspect is a memory leak in his program.